# Javascript variable not displaying the number assigned to it

Tags: javascript, numbers

I'm writing a javascript program that needs random 10-digit numbers which can sometimes have the 10th digit as 0. I assigned a variable to one of these numbers and then logged it to make sure everything was alright...but it wasn't. Here is my code:

```
var candidate = 0135740250;
var candidate2 = 0272189318;
console.log(candidate); // Returns 24625320
console.log(candidate2); // Returns 272189318
```

I tried taking the `0` off the beginning of `candidate`, and that made it return correctly, but I don't understand why it doesn't work in the first place. I included `candidate2` above because whatever I do to it, adding `0`s in the middle, changing it in other ways, it stays correct, so I can't figure out why `candidate` is being screwed up. I vaguely understand the number storage system in Javascript and that its not perfect, but I need a predictable, repeatable way to return the correct number.

The question is: what is happening here and how can I reliably avoid it?

Comment: convert the number to string before doing anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"The question is: what is happening here..."*

The first is a valid octal, so it gets converted as such.

The second is not a valid octal because of the `8` and `9`, so it gets the base 10 representation with the leading `0` removed since it adds no value.

---

> *"...and how can I reliably avoid it?"*

Avoiding it will depend on how you're generating your numbers. If you were using `.random()` it wouldn't be an issue, so I'd assume they're coming from some sort of string representation.

If so, and if you're using `parseInt()` to get the actual number, then pass it `10` as the second argument to ensure base-10 representation.

Comment: A way to fix it is to be in "strict" mode, since octal constants are not recognized then (they're always parsed as base 10).

Comment: @Pointy: Yet another reason to use strict mode. :-) I believe ECMAScript 6 has a new syntax for octals `0o123`.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript treats any number beginning with 0 as octal if it is a valid octal.

Answer (score 0):

Another quack is, if you know the length of string to generate

```
"use strict"
var strlent = 10
console.log(candidate2.toString().length < strlent ? "0" + 
candidate2.toString() : candidate2.toString())
>>>0272189318
```